# Как реализовать на Python 3 удаление определенного приложения(программы) на Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10

То есть мне надо написать код, который удаляет определенную программу, желательно без участия пользователя.
Удаляемая программа **не** wmic (т.е. установлена не установщиком Windows), поэтому, например, такой код не подойдет:

```
import os
path = 'file.bat'
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    s = 'wmic product where name="{}" call uninstall /nointeractive'.format('Название программы')
    f.write(s)
os.startfile(path)
```

Я так понял нужно использовать тоже bat-файл, но команда нужна другая. Наверное.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Используйте os.remove("путь до файла") - удаление файла
- os.rmdir("путь до файла") - удаление пустой папки
- shutil.rmtree("путь до файла") - удаление папки с файлами

**Обратите внимание:** python воспринимает только пути, в которых нет одиночного \ - (backslash). Например, он примет путь D:/папка/файл или C:\\папка\\файл. Но **не** примет D:\папка\файл.

И так, пример использования shutil.rmtree():

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("D:/111/new")
```

---

Если вы хотите удалять что-либо через .bat файл - нужно создать .bat файл и записать в него команду:
(выберите наиболее подходящую)

- del "адрес файла" (удаляет одиночный файл или все файлы из папки, сохраняя папку)
- rd "адрес файла" (удаляет папку)
- rmdir делает тоже, что и rd

Вы можете добавить в конце строки или после самой команды:

- /s - будут удалены все вложения (в противном случае вы получите
  уведомление папка не пуста и она не будет удалена)
- /Q удаляет файлы без подтверждения. Иначе появится окно:

> D:\111\Новая папка, вы уверены [Y(да)/N(нет)]?

Пример команды:

```
rd "D:\111\Новая папка" /s /Q
```

---

Файл готов, теперь его нужно запустить через python. Для этого используйте subprocess

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('адрес файла')
```

Popen это не опечатка, команда появилась от слов "process open"

---

Вам нужно будет записать пути вручную или вводить корректные пути, который может воспринять python либо добавить префикс r в начало строки. Пример: `shutil.rmtree(r"C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\Новая папка")`

Comment: subprocess.Popen('адрес файла') а что если пишет что AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'popen'

Comment: `if a == "1":
    print("удаление....")
    time.sleep(4)
    subprocess.popen("C:/Users/azats/Desktop/file.bat")` вот часть кода. Да вроде нет, везде разные названия

Comment: Popen пишется обязательно с большой буквы)

Comment: Да, теперь ошибку не выдаёт, но почему то содержимое папки не удаляет. Вот код для bat-файла, который использовал: `del C:\Users\azats\Desktop\ВСЕ ИГРЫ /s /Q`

Comment: почему то пишет Не удается найти C:\Users\azats\Desktop\╨Т╨б╨Х если запускать питон-файл с командной строки

Comment: Используйте shutil.rmtree("D:/111/new"), а файл найти не может потому что работает некорректно с \

Comment: Если при запуске bat файла не работает, то нужно исправлять файл

Comment: Файл находит, папку не находит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107353/discussion-between--and-azkoreo).

Comment: Если у вас возникают такие же ошибки - решение в чате

Comment: Если перед именем писать r, то не потребуются двойные \\

Comment: Я добавил это в ответ